# Real-time chat between 2 different android applications

Tags: android, laravel, firebase, real-time, pusher

Okay Guys , sorry if this seems to be emotional subject  , 
Me ( Backend dev ) and The android guy have an issue that we can't handle
we have 2 different mobile apps their backbone endpoints built with laravel
and it's supposed that they have chat system between each other you know like clients app that request some services and provider app who will make it , we are using firebase and as you know am having 2 different FCM Key for each app . so for real time i head to pusher and use new Beams they provide to implement the real time functionality , but no hope cause Beams accepts only one FCM Key , so is it possible to achieve this challenge to make 2 different apps talks to each other in realtime or not , and if the answer is yes , could you provide any guidelines , cause am still digging the internet with no hope , 
thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use XMPP protocol or MQTT protocol as a mediator on Laravel Backend.

Both are real-time communication protocol and available for all platforms.

The flow will be

1st App (sends data to another app's **unique id** ) -> Server tells **MQTT** or **XMPP** or **Firebase** to push data onto another app.

You can use different Controller and model with different Firebase ID on laravel for communication with two diffrent applications.